# Build time based bars using stock tick data

Tags: c#, algorithmic-trading

I'm trying to build stock market Bar (snapshot) data at run-time using tick data. My stock data provider provides access to tick level data where I have an event called OnTick that is triggered whenever a new tick is sent by the data provider. I'm hoping to do one of the two below, or if someone can suggest a good option:

**Option 1:**

In this option I maintain a Bar object and update it each time I get a tick. The OnBar() event can be attached to a timer elapsed event (1 minute for 1 minute bars etc).

```
//TickMsg = double price, DateTime dttm
public void OnTick(TickMsg newTick)
{
    TaskFactory.StartNew(){UpdateBar(newTick)};//Syntax not specific
}

UpdateBar()
{
            //nextBar is a Bar object thats intialized to Open = 0, High = 0, Low = 0, Close = 0
    if(nextBar.Open==0)
       nextBar.Open = newTick.price;

    if(newTick.price>nextBar.High)
       nextBar.High = newTick.price;

    if(newTick.price<nextBar.Low)
       nextBar.Low = newTick.price;

       nextBar.Close = newTick.price;

}

public void OnBar(Bar bar)
{
    //Process the bar..perform calculations etc
    bar = new Bar(0,0,0,0);//Reset the bar
}
```

**Option 2:**

In this option I'm just adding the tick to a list of ticks and perform the calculations when OnBar is called. The OnBar() event can be attached to a timer elapsed event (1 minute for 1 minute bars etc).

```
List <TickMsg> TickList;
public void OnTick(TickMsg newTick)
{
     TickList.Add(newTick);
}

public void OnBar()//called on a timer
{
     var low = TickList.Min();
     var high = TickList.Max();
     var close = (from entry in TickList orderby entry.TickMsg.dttm ascending).Last();
     var open = (from entry in TickList orderby entry.TickMsg.dttm ascending).First();

     TickList.Empty(); 
}
```

**Questions:**

- Which approach is more processing intensive?
- Which approach requires more memory?

Again, if someone has a suggestion on an alternative approach, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you need to display or access the bar before it's completed? In case option 2 seems not to achieve that. Option 1 I can never imagine will be a performance clog. And it will use less memory, as you don't seem to save the tick data to any variable.

Comment: Even option 1 doesn't achieve what you suggested, it publishes after the time is complete. However you are right that we eventually went with 1, even tho the code isn't as simple as it looks here.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach it is the second. 
When you reset the bar on first approach, the lowest price will never be less than zero, so, the low price on bar will be always zero.

Comment: Agreed - there was a logical error in the code and the below line should be setting Max Number for low while resetting.
bar = new Bar(0,0,0,0); 

However the question was asked more from a performance perspective and we went with option 1.

Answer (score 0):

[Trade link](http://code.google.com/p/tradelink/) is a good example on how it is done. Their tutorials cover this. Also since it is open source you can have a peek into how it is done. [The getting started tutorial is here.](http://code.google.com/p/tradelink/wiki/TradeLink)

Comment: Thanks, will check out what approach trade-link follows, however I must add that the crux of my query was to discuss the trade-offs and benefits of the different options. The approach followed by trade-link may not be the best approach for my system.